# Changing list-style-image upon click

Tags: jquery, css

I have a list with a `list` image of a little plus sign.  Here is the `javascript` to toggle the lists:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('#main li ul').hide();
      $('#main li').click(function() {
      $(this).children('ul').slideToggle("slow");
      });
});
```

What I'd like to be able to do is that when I click one of the months, the sign changes to a minus sign located [here](http://i.imgur.com/0X7n5.png)

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/E8xKJ/1/) is a link to a `fiddle` of a working list so far.

Any ideas of what would be the simplest way to make the image change?
​

Comment: you don't have the image there in fiddle

Comment: It should be there - works fine for me.
http://jsfiddle.net/E8xKJ/3/

Comment: @joshft91 There is no padding, so it doesn't work. Have completed a fiddle for you. Posting it as an answer. Please wait.

Comment: @joshft91 Please check http://jsfiddle.net/RPpgQ/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/RPpgQ/

**CSS**

```
#main {
    cursor:pointer;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

#main li {list-style-image: url('http://static.nahoku.com/skin/frontend/enterprise/nahoku/images/plus-icon.gif');}
#main li.open {list-style-image: url('http://avnetexpress.avnet.com/wcsstore/emstore/images/prodnav-minus-sm.gif');}

#main ul {
     list-style-image: none;
}​
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#main li ul').hide();
    $('#main li').click(function() {
        $(this).children('ul').slideToggle("slow");
        $(this).toggleClass('open');
    });
});
​
```

Comment: Thanks!  How would I go about making the ul lists inside outer lists not display the + symbol?  They are showing up for me.

Comment: @joshft91 Replace `#main li` with `#main > li`.

Comment: Ah, I got it - and yup, was just waiting to see if I could get it to work.  You got yourself an accept - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('#main li ul').hide();
      $('#main li').click(function() {
        $(this).children('ul').slideToggle("slow");
        $(this).toggleClass('minus');  /*img gets applied to ul - not li */
   });
});
```

then

```
.minus{
   list-style-image:url('http://minus_img');
 }
```

Comment: @joshft91 - sorry , edited , take .parent() out , you will not need it

Comment: also for url you have to put the actual image in there,  i just wrote minus_img